I would like to ask you about PopScope and go_router. I'm afraid it should have any issue
I'm trying to catch a PopScope event. I've tried but without success. Here is my code. I'll simplify it a bit:
GoRoute(
  path: '/group/:groupId',
  builder: (context, state) {
    final groupId = state.pathParameters['groupId']!;
    final extras = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>?;

    logger.t('NR.goRoute: Grupo: $groupId. Extras recibidos: ${(extras == null) ? null : extras['fr']}');

    return PopScope(
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop,_) async {
        logger.w('This log is not printed');
        if (!didPop & context.mounted) {
          context.go('/groups'); // Navegar de vuelta a /groups
        }
      },
      child: Group__Screen(
        groupId: groupId,
        groupName: extras?['groupName'] ?? '',
        groupColor: extras?['groupColor'] ?? Colors.blue,
        fr: extras?['fr'],
      ),
    );
  },
),

I've develop a button to get back, and it works fine. But for some reason, I can't use the "back" method Android native, button or gesture.
I don't know why it didn't work. There is no more PopScope that can be truncate that PopScore. There is no Navigation.go() or whatelse. This is the develop of my button, that works fine.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final bloc = context.read<Group__Bloc>();

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(groupName),
      backgroundColor: groupColor,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () async => context.go('/groups'),
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
          onPressed: () => _handleDeepLinkShare(context),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: 

That icon works fine. But back gesture doesn't even print the log with Warning level.
I'm trying to use a physical Android Pixel 7 to debug, in a Mac Air. I don't know if it's related with it, but I don't know what I can do more.
Any idea to avoid PopScope?

I've tried to disable the back gesture in order to keep the button as only option to go back, but without success.

A friend told me it doesn't understand well. The native "back" button from Android as well as the "back" gesture, slicing from the lateral to the center, both methods skip the app. But the "back" button develop with Flutter works fine. I want to know if there is any solution for what I pretend.

Did you try providing value on  canPop

Yes, but without success. I've been stuck here some days. Believe me. I've tried all the functionality of willPopScope, popScope, onWillPop, onPopInvoked, onPopInvokedWithResult, canPop....

I think it is solved. It was related with the way I define the routes relations. There is more complicated than I thought. I need to check my new theory, as soon as I confirm it, I’ll close this ask. Sorry for bored you.

Done, thanks for the tip

Finally I've found my error. It seems that I need to use nested routes to make the navigation backwards possible without exiting the app. Now it's better than ever.
GoRoute(
  path: '/groups',
  builder: (context, state) => const PopScope(
    canPop:false,
    child: GroupsScreen(),
  ),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: 'avatar-selector',
      builder: (context, state) => PopScope(
        onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
        if (didPop) {
             logger.d('Popped from group route');
        } else {
             logger.d('Popped from group route with result: $result');
        }
      },
      child: const AvatarSelectorScreen(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: ':groupId',
      builder: (context, state) {
      final groupId = state.pathParameters['groupId']!;
      final extras = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>?;
      logger.d('Building group route for $groupId');
      return PopScope(
        onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
          if (didPop) {
            logger.d('Popped from group route'); // I finally see this log!!!!
          } else {
            logger.d('Popped from group route with result: $result');
          }
        },
      child: Group__Screen(...),
      );
    },
  ),
],
),

It works fine now 
